# How can I redirect user/*/edit to another page based on user content?

Tags: users, theming

I have a site with the following relationship: for every user, there is one corresponding (node) profile. For the user/*/edit, I would like the user to actually edit their profile node, not the user account. I've thought about preprocessing the page template to make something available in order to then re-write the secondary menu in the template - but which variable can I use? It's not available in the $user array.

Comment: you are playing with fire here in a lot of ways, but what version of drupal are you using?

Comment: you have query the database to get the back reference, otherwise you can also keep the user node id on user entity also which will be udpated when a node is referred to a uid, that way you can have it on $user also.

Comment: @Jimajamma, I'm using D7.

Comment: @arpitr - How would I keep the the user nid on the user entity? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: and are you using any module for the nodes as a profile or doing this all yourself?

Comment: answer for jimajamma question is important. Assuming the user node is from a content type that you have created and not coming from any module, the time node get saved, there must be  user reference field, so you can hook the node_update process and check the user reference field value then save the current nid to the user entity corresponding to that uid.

Comment: I'm not using another module, the profile nodes are not entities. @arpitr - are you suggesting that I add another field to the node for user reference? I've had a lot of trouble with both the node reference and entity reference projects, especially with my content types already developed, the references break for some reason. I've used this kind of relationship in the past, I'm not sure why this time it's different. I'm looking into using relation project now.

Comment: I was asking to make sure it wasn't already done for you.  If you can pretty much guarantee that there is only one such profile node per user, I can map out the broad strokes here for you

Comment: @Jimajamma I guess we can assume one node per user - "here is one corresponding (node) profile"

Comment: There is exactly one corresponding profile node per user.

Comment: you do not have to create reference field if you have relation in place, I wonder if relations are both ways or not, I have never used relation before just as an idea I can suggest you can do a custom query to get the user-node relation mapping and create a helper function which takes the user as argument and returns the node related and simply the time you need to get the node call this function with global $user(uid).

Comment: Please be more specific about your needs. Anyhow, I think you can consider using page manager module. You can use so many different things like redirecting, making custom pages, using page manager contexts to load metadata related to the pages, defining access rules and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I added an entity reference field to both the the user and profile node. In the page template, I can user_load() the uid of the logged-in user and have the entity reference available for theming.

Answer (score 0):

So in broad strokes, basically what you want to do is grab the user's uid and then open for editing the corresponding profile type node owned by that user.

So, if you have that user's uid in `$uid`, it would be something along these lines:

```
$nid = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->condition('n.type', 'YOUR_PROFILE_NODE_TYPE')
        ->condition('n.uid', $uid)
        ->fields('n', array('nid'))
        ->execute()->fetchField();
```

which, if I've not typo'ed anything will set `$nid` to the node id of the node of type YOUR_PROFILE_NODE_TYPE that is owned by `$uid`.

If there is only one, that's the node we are looking for.

So, now you just need to create a link to `node/$nid/edit` and you're all set.  (Somewhat obviously, you want to present this link only to admins and the user who owns the profile.)

So, where do you put all of this?

Of course, you could preprocess this into a variable that's used in a page template, but you could also create a new menu item as well, eg `user/#/edit-profile` that grabs the user id out of the second argument and then does all of the above to grab the actual nid and then presents the node edit form, but now we are getting past the broad strokes :)  (But [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) is the place to look, with `user.module` a great starting point for example code for `user/#/edit` to modify)

Comment: This looks great, but I'm not getting anything usable if I put it in _themename_ _preprocess. Here's what I'm doing   `$uid = $variables['user']->uid;  
 $nid = db_select('node', 'n')  
 ->condition('n.type', 'fellow_profile')  
 ->condition('n.uid', $uid)  
 ->fields('n', array('nid'))  
 ->execute()->fetchField();  
$variables['profile_nid'][] = $nid;`

Comment: I doubt there is a `user` variable being sent in via `preprocess()`, but it is available in the second argument.  Once again, broad strokes here, it would be `1` if you were looking at `user/1/edit-profile` or just plain old `user/1` and can be found via `arg(1)` (no relation to user 1 and 1 here, arg(#) just returns the #th argument in the path).

Comment: You're right, there isn't, but I can user_load() and have it - but, that won't give me the reference to the profile node. My solution is to use an entity reference field on each (user and profile), which gives me just what I need. Thanks for all your brainstorming!

Answer (score 0):

Consider making a new solution based on [Profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2), otherwise spice you current solution up with the [Rules module](https://drupal.org/project/rules). :)